# How to scale down part of an object evenly?

Tags: modeling, transforms

Sorry this seems like the most noob question ever, but I'm not sure how to google it specifically.

How can i scale down this long part of my mesh so it's "skinnier"? If i select all the faces and scale it stretches the joined part too. [image][image: Not scaling how id like]

I've tried locking the scale to different axis' as well but they look out of proportion like this:

[image]

I want the keep the length the same but make it skinnier.

Thanks!

Comment: S > Shift-X was exactly what I needed. Thank you! - I'd like to be able to mark your comment as a solution but i don't think I can on a comment?

Comment: Ok. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks from your image as if you want to keep the <kbd>X</kbd> length the same. in which case use <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>Shift-X</kbd> to scale just in the <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> direction. You may need to change the <kbd>Transform Pivot Point</kbd> setting first, but you haven't shown the top menu bar so we can't see how it's currently set.